# Sorting a many to many relation with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: sorting, laravel, many-to-many, eloquent, relationship

I do have swatches table,  a colors table and a swatch_color pivot table.

Relations are set as:

```
public function colors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Color');
}

public function swatches()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Swatch');
}
```

I have no problem to retrieve the swatches with the color relations

```
$swatches = Swatch::with('colors')->get();
return dd($swatches);
```

Colors is always an array of 5 color objects with hue, R, G, and B attributes.

Now I would like to sort the swatches by the R value of the first related color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need to sort `$swatches` collection:

```
$swatches->sortBy(function ($swatch) {
  return ($color = $swatch->colors->first())
     ? $color->r
     : null;
});
```

Another way would be manual `joining` the tables.

You can use `sortByDesc` for descending order.

Comment: This answer is correct, it works fine. I came up with a solution where I used the toArray() and then sorted the array, but your solution is much nicer. What I have learned though is that both are very slow (11-12 secs on 500 swatch records with 5 relations each) . So I ended up storing the colors directly in the swatch model, which is lightning fast. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, collection sorting isn't something you'd like to do with lot of records. DB should be used for that, so that's the way I would suggest as well.

Comment: Something just as fast without adding columns on the table is to cache the result of this operation (Google 'laravel cache')

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution

```
$collection = collect($arr);
     $sorted = $collection->sortBy(function($vv, $kk) {
           return [$vv['isFriend'],$vv['isCoworker'],$vv['icecount']];
            });

 $finalArr = $sorted->values()->all();
```