# Custom sorting on a laravel relationship collection

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm a little stuck on something that usually is quite straight forward. I need to sort records from a hasMany relationship into a custom order based on a certain value and an 'sort order' array.

My code below doesn't work because I'm passing uSort() a eloquent collection and I'm not sure how to get around it.

```
$go = $this->hasMany('Product')->orderBy('colour','DESC');

$order = array('RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE', 'YELLOW');

usort($go, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a->colour, $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b->colour, $order);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});

return $go;
```

Maybe I'm missing some amazing laravel magic helper, but I'm stuck. Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Can you please post the array structure of `$go` like as `print_r($go)` along with the expected output

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The **usort** equivalent for **Collection** is the **sort()** method. It takes a callback as a parameter and returns the sorted collection.

So in your case, the solution is:

```
$go = $go->sort(function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
  $pos_a = array_search($a->colour, $order);
  $pos_b = array_search($b->colour, $order);
  return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});
```

Comment: This has worked after moving it outside the relationship definition, since relationship functions must return a relationship. Thanks for the great example!

Answer (score 2):

Your sorting will be applied only after you get the result while here **`$go = $this->hasMany('Product')->orderBy('colour','DESC');`** you are just getting an instance of a class which will return can return your result if you apply a **`get`** method on it.

For your purpose you have to use **`sortBy method`** of **`laravel collections`** after you get the result of your data you can find more [(**laravel Collection sortBy() method)**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby) & here is a similar question answer for you **https://stackoverflow.com/a/28202985**

Comment: Thanks for the info about applying this outside the relationship function. Between you and jedrzej you've solved my problem, cheers!