# How do I remap my array keys using an array of integers?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my original array of items

```php
$items = [
    0 => 'item 1',
    1 => 'item 2',
    2 => 'item 3'
];
```

I want to change the order of the items based on their keys, so I'm doing this...

```php
$reorder = [2,0,1];

uksort($items, function($key1, $key2) use ($reorder) {
    return (array_search($key1, $reorder) > array_search($key2, $reorder));
});
```

This works as it should, and produces the proper results.

```php
$items = [
    2 => 'item 3',
    0 => 'item 1',
    1 => 'item 2'
];
```

However, when returning that in Laravel as json the newly ordered `$items` reverts back to the original order, which is obviously not what I want.

Is there a way to remap the array keys while reordering them?

Comment: Not answer to "a way to remap the array keys while reordering them", but `array_values()` returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically. So you can `return response()->json(array_values($items));`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ That actually patched my problem, and will work if I can't get them remapped.Thanks!

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I may have spoke too soon. This introduces an array key where one wasn't before. When returning in the API, it used to be `"items": [{"id": 1,"name": "Item One",}` and now it's `"items": {"8": {"id": 9,"name": "Item Nine",},` which may throw off the app on the receiving end of the API call.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you with the information you provide in the question. I read the comments in Furkan's reply, where you say "I'm taking a collection and reordering it". So if you are using collections it could be all easier using the [available methods](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#available-methods) for collections. For example `->values()` will give you a result similar to PHP's `array_values()`. You can try `response()->json(collect($items)->values());`

Comment: Also what you do with `uksort` could be done with some collections method like `sort()` or [sortKeys()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortkeys). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31983510/7498116).

Comment: I actually got it sorted out using `array_values()` by doing something along the lines of `$items = array_values($items)` and then `return response()->json($items)`. That retained the new order and removed the new key. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you returning the array in Laravel? The following example works for me exactly as you want it.

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $items = [
        0 => 'item 1',
        1 => 'item 2',
        2 => 'item 3'
    ];

    $reorder = [2,0,1];
    uksort($items, function($key1, $key2) use ($reorder) {
        return (array_search($key1, $reorder) > array_search($key2, $reorder));
    });

    return response()->json($items);
    // {"2":"item 3","0":"item 1","1":"item 2"}
});
```

If you have tried it in a browser, keep in mind that some browsers automatically reorder json arrays. In that case you have to get the raw instead of the formatted data.

Comment: I'm testing in Postman. Your example will work because you're not reordering the array after you created it. I'm taking a collection and reordering it, which works fine if I `dd()` it, but after passing it through `response()->json()` it's back to the original order.

Comment: I have edited the example in my post. The order of the array keys is still correct for me. Are you really sure that your browser is not automatically formatting the json data?

Comment: Yes, your example works, however my example is a simplified version of what I'm actually doing, which is why I want to remap the keys.